# What reference material exists for writing my own -vsdoc.js for JS Intellisense in VS2008?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, vsdoc

I've got the vsdoc for jquery working in my project, but I'd also like to get intellisense for my own JS files - including the verbose `<param>`, `<field>`, and `<returns>` tags and so on.  Where can I find a specification for the format of those comments, beyond the -vsdoc.js for jquery?

Comment: Great question.  I tried finding stuff for it on Google, but not a lot out there other than how to integrate the -vsdoc and jQuery together in visual studio...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx) explaining how to do some JavaScript XML documentation

But personally I would just look at jQuery's -vsdoc file for reference.

Comment: That blog post is 5 years old. Is there anything more recent? Anything official?